# Within a range, get the percentage of a number's closeness to the mean value

Tags: percentages, means

Say I have a range: **50** through **90**, therefore the mean value is **70**.

I would like a formula to return the percentage from a given value within that range, based on how close it is to this (middle) value.

So:
**50** would return **0%**
**60** would return **50%**
**70** would return **100%**
**80** would return **50%**
**90** would return **0%**

I'm trying to find a formula that could take these parameters to return such a percentage.

Thank you in advance for any help provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has been able to help with this one so far. I have a solution, but it requires two steps, plus an if condition for the second step.. preferably this would use a single formula which I am sure is possible but I can't seem to work it out. My 2 step solution is as follows:

Step 1: **((input - min) / ((max - min) / 2)) * 100**
If output of step 1 is above 100 then apply the following:
Step 2: **Abs(200 - output)**

Using this process with a couple of examples:
((60 - 50) / ((90 - 50) / 2)) * 100 == **50%**
((70 - 50) / ((90 - 50) / 2)) * 100 == **100%**
((80 - 50) / ((90 - 50) / 2)) * 100 == 150 (Step 2): Abs(200 - 150) == **50%**

So this is producing the results I need but the second step is required. If this isn't possible with one step then I will have to accept this as the answer I guess.